# How would I make one of these tabs active active on load in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to think angular but am not sure how to assign a value to an element on load like in jQuery.

I have the following tabs, all of which become 'selected' on click. How do I select one on load so that one tab is 'selected' without the user having to do anything?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-class="{active: selected == 1}">
     <a href="" ng-click="selected=1">Overview</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: selected == 2}">
     <a href="" ng-click="selected=2">My Properties</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: selected == 3}">
     <a href="" ng-click="selected=3">Potential Properties</a>
    </li>
</ul>


<div ng-if="selected == 1">
    <div ng-include=" 'views/dash/_overview.html' "></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="selected == 2">
    <div ng-include=" 'views/dash/_myproperties.html' "></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="selected == 3">
    <div ng-include=" 'views/dash/_buyproperties.html' "></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller at the start have

```
$scope.selected = 1;
```

But you probably should put it in an object to keep the $scope clean

```
$scope.data = {
   selectedTab:1
};
```

and

```
<li ng-class="{active: data.selectedTab == 1}">
<div ng-if="data.selectedTab == 1">
```

etc

Comment: Thanks. Think I need to read up more as to why it needs to be put into an object.

Comment: @JoeIsaacson For that take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21286131/560593) to a question about wither or not to use an object like this.